# Transitioning Storyboard Effect in Corona SDK not Transitioning Properly

Tags: sdk, coronasdk

In my code, I have am using the storyboard to transition between two .lua files. However, the effect used to transition between them is not present even though the transition itself is taking place. So essentially, the storyboard succesuflly transitions between the two files, but is accompanied with none of the effects specified. Does anyone know why this is happening?

First Scene:

```
local storyboard = require( "storyboard" )

local scene = storyboard.newScene()

------------------------------------------Set Background
local backgroundFillColor = {}

--Red RGB
backgroundFillColor[1] = 76/255

--Greeb RGB
backgroundFillColor[2] = 217/255

--Blue RGB
backgroundFillColor[3] = 100/255

 display.setDefault("background",backgroundFillColor[1],backgroundFillColor[2],backgroundFillColor[3])



local function changeScene( event )
   -- body
    if event.phase == "ended" then
        storyboard.gotoScene( "scene1", "fade", 500 )   -- go to levels scene
    end

 end

Runtime:addEventListener( "touch", changeScene )

return scene
```

Second Scene:

```
local storyboard = require( "storyboard" )

local scene = storyboard.newScene()

------------------------------------------Set Background
local backgroundFillColor = {}

--Red RGB
backgroundFillColor[1] = 0/255

--Greeb RGB
backgroundFillColor[2] = 0/255

--Blue RGB
backgroundFillColor[3] = 0/255

 display.setDefault("background",backgroundFillColor[1],backgroundFillColor[2],backgroundFillColor[3])



local function changeScene( event )
   -- body
    if event.phase == "ended" then
        storyboard.gotoScene( "scene", "fade", 500 )    -- go to levels scene
    end

 end

Runtime:addEventListener( "touch", changeScene )

return scene
```

Main:

```
display.setStatusBar( display.HiddenStatusBar )

-- include the Corona "storyboard" module
local storyboard = require "storyboard"

storyboard.gotoScene( "scene", "fade", 5000 )   -- go to levels scene
```

Comment: Looks like you haven't correctly setup the storyboard. Lacking functions such as `createScene`, `willEnterScene`, `exitScene` and `destroyScene` which is required for storyboard to function correctly. I suggest you read the storyboard documentation. Or the new composer, which is replacing storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

You must insert any display object that you want Storyboard to manage (i.e. transition around) into the scene's "view" group.  Normally you create all of these objects in the createScene() function where you setup a reference to the view, i.e.

```
function scene:createScene( event ) 
  local group = self.view
  local background = display.newImageRect("somebackgroundimage.png", width, height)
  group:insert( background )
  ...
end
```

The **group:insert( background )** is critical for the functioning of Storyboard (and Composer)